# How to get certain path in JAX-RS?

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

like, if my request is /me/myname/is/foo

I have designated like this in JAX-RS

```
@Path("myName/{var}")
public String getN(@PathParam("var") String s) {

    //my request has to lie here. It doesn't because it has one more resource.. I want to create sth like after /myname, Everything is to be on this method. How to do this?

    //like I wanted path value to be /is/foo



}
```

Comment: Use a regex `"myName/{var: .*}"`. This will allow anything. If you want to also accept just `/myname` then you could do something like `"myName{var: (/.*)?}"`

Comment: You could use `@PathParam("var") List<PathSegment>` as a param to get separated segments so you don't need to parse everything yourself. See the [PathSegment API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/PathSegment.html)